# MySql now() Warning 1264 Out of range issue

Tags: mysql

If I do,

```
SELECT NOW(),
```

I will have `2013-10-26 1:36`.
Ok, lets say I have a **table (field1,datetime)**.

Now I do,

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (field1,datetime) VALUES ("BLAH",SELECT NOW());
```

So I have this `warning :1264 out of range`.
It inserts **`BLAH and 0000-00-00 00:00:00`**.

Does anyone have an idea to solve this issue?

Comment: What's the type of `TABLE1.datetime`

Comment: Why do you have `SELECT NOW()` in the `VALUES(...)` clause? It should be only be `NOW()`.Also date/time depends upon a specific zone that should be handled with care.

Comment: @Lion is right. No `SELECT` in `VALUES()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the type of your `datetime` column ?

I followed below steps and its worked as charm.

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE1 (field1 VARCHAR(20), datetime DATETIME);
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (field1,datetime) VALUES ("BLAH", NOW());
```

Here is the [Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a2c45).

Answer (score 0):

Try just to insert into Datetime field, like this '2013-10-26 1:36'
i think it is because of the seconds.